# Разрешения групп в django

Tags: python, django

где находится файл models с group_permissions? Мне нужно получить к этим разрешениям доступ, для изменения оных через код, но в django.contrib.auth.models не нашел. И как эта таблица называется в коде?

Изображение, для лучшего понимания, какая таблица мне нужна (точнее ее имя и местонахождение).[image: изображение, для улучшения понимания требуемой информации]